# Select entries from arrays in Java

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

I have a two-dimensional array such as {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5,6}}. I want to take one element from each array and create all combinations from these unless they only differ in one place so for this example a possible solution would be.

{1, 3, 5}, {1, 4, 6}, {2, 3, 6}, {2, 4, 5}

{1, 3, 6} as an example only differs in the third position from the first in the result so it should be excluded. It feels like a recursive approach should be able to do this, but cant really work it out.

The approach needs to work for a bigger array in both dimensions and the inner arrays does not have to be of the same size. Max index sizes for the first dimension is 8 and for the second roughly 20.

Comment: This site is not for these stuff(just asking a problem) tell us what you have tried and your code!

Comment: do `{1, 3}` and `{1, 3, 5}` differ in exactly one place, i.e. the end?

Comment: I have not really tried anything as I cant really put my finger on where to start. I have made a naive version that goes through all possible combinations and compares them with the ones I have found already, but it gets slow. 

{1, 3} and {1 ,3, 5} does differ as they are of different lengths. I only needs where they are full length, but that would be a simple problem to find too short arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not usual and not appreciated on SO to give recommendations for a library but in this case I would make an exception and recommend you to have a look at [combinatoricslib3-example](https://github.com/dpaukov/combinatoricslib3-example) before you reinvent the wheel. It is a library that is java 8 compatible and allows you to create subsets, combinations, Cartesian Product (by the way this is the right term for your task), permuttions ... in a fast and easy way

For your example the code could look something like:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import org.paukov.combinatorics3.Generator;

public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        Integer[][] myArray =  {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5,6}};

        Generator.cartesianProduct(Arrays.asList(myArray[0]), Arrays.asList(myArray[1]), Arrays.asList(myArray[2]))
           .stream()
           .forEach(System.out::println);        
    }  
}
```

This will produce:

```
[1, 3, 5]
[1, 3, 6]
[1, 4, 5]
[1, 4, 6]
[2, 3, 5]
[2, 3, 6]
[2, 4, 5]
[2, 4, 6]
```

which you can filter according to your requirements. Works also with jagged array ( multidimensional array where member arrays are of different size).

**EDIT**

To make the above more readable you can first collect the source array to a list of lists. I added also an example filtering which excludes such lists which only differ on the last elemnet as mentioned in your question.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {        
    Integer[][] myArray =  {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5,6}};

    List<List<Integer>> myList = Arrays.stream(myArray)
                                      .map(arr -> Arrays.asList(arr))
                                      .collect(Collectors.toList());

    Generator.cartesianProduct(myList)
             .stream()
             .collect(Collectors.toMap(list -> list.subList(0, list.size()-1), p -> p, (p, q) ->p))
             .values()
             .stream()
             .forEach(System.out::println);        
}
```

**NOTE**

The number of elements in the Cartesian product `A×B×⋯×N` is `|A|*|B|⋯|N|`, i.e total product of the number of elements in each set: for your example array of `3x2` the total count is `2*2*2 = 2^3 = 8`. After filtering the half (4). This means for what you are trying to do with an `8x20` array `20^8 = 25.600.000.000` even after filtering there will remain `12.800.000.000`

Comment: This was a nice way of generating all the entries.

Comment: @MarkusHervén Edited my post after your update with the additional info of your dimenssions.

Comment: Thanks, will try it out, the difference does not have to be in the last index though but can be in any of them so the reduction in size will be much larger. That is why I want to try to only generate the needed entries instead of generating them all and then remove the ones I do not need.

Comment: I could not fully solve this by using recursion or any other way. Found a trick that will remove most of the rows that I do not want. Select one of the original arrays and remove all but one entry in it. That will get me pretty close to the answer I seek by then just getting all combinations with the rest, close enough for me case.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think recursion is the way to go here. If you upscale a lot you can easily run in a StackOverflowException...

I would rather create all combinations (e.g. like @Eritrean did) and then remove all elements that differ in one place. This could cause other problems if you upscale to much, but i think it is the better way.

You can use something like this to remove elements that differ in one place:

```
int[][] arr = {{1, 3, 5}, {1, 3, 6}, {1, 4, 5}, {1, 4, 6}, {2, 3, 5}, {2, 3, 6}, {2, 4, 5}, {2, 4, 6}}; //All combinations
Set<Integer> removeIndexes = new HashSet<>(); //A list of all indexes that should be removed
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) { //go through each element
    if (removeIndexes.contains(i)) continue; //stop if this element is already sorted out
    for (int k = i + 1; k < arr.length; k++) { //go through each element, starting with the next after i
        if (removeIndexes.contains(k)) continue; //stop if this element is already sorted out
        int equal = 0; //number of equal integers in comprehension
        for (int j = 0; j < arr[0].length; j++) { //go through each element in the inner array
            if (arr[i][j] == arr[k][j]) { //compare the element i with the element k (each with the inner index j)
                equal++; //if they have the same value at the same inner index increase equal by 1
            }
        } // the comparison between index i and k is done. "equal" indicates the number of identical inner elements.
        if (equal >= arr[0].length - 1) { //check if there is just one unequal value
            removeIndexes.add(k); //if so, add the index k to the list
        }
    }
}
```

Removing all the indexes of the Set to create a new array could look like this:

```
int[][] newArray = new int[arr.length - removeIndexes.size()][arr[0].length];
int c = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (!(removeIndexes.contains(i))) {
        newArray[c++] = arr[i];
    }
}
```

In your example this code would make

```
{1,3,5}, {1,4,6}, {2,3,6}, {2,4,5}
```

out of

```
{1,3,5}, {1,3,6}, {1,4,5}, {1,4,6}, {2,3,5}, {2,3,6}, {2,4,5}, {2,4,6}
```

Comment: Will try this and see if I can get it to perform. When it comes to size the max sizes are roughly 8 in the first dimension and 20 in the second.

Comment: @MarkusHervén With these sizes you should not have any iterative or recursive problems.